# Remove all rows of a table if the check box is checked?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have below table in my jsp.

```
<table class="myTable" id="myTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing: 0; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr class="impClass">
        <td class="myClass">
            <div>
                <label for="delete">Delete</label>
                <br>
                <input class="mySecondClass" type="checkbox" id="delete" name="delete">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="impClass">
        <td class="myClass">
            <div>
                <label for="delete">Delete</label>
                <br>
                <input class="mySecondClass" type="checkbox" id="delete" name="delete">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="impClass">
        <td class="myClass">
            <div>
                <label for="delete">Delete</label>
                <br>
                <input class="mySecondClass" type="checkbox" id="delete" name="delete">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to delete all rows of a table if their delete check box is checked. How can i remove all the rows from the `table` whose delete check box is checked using `jquery`?

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: your markup is invalid because of non-unique ids

Comment: `$(".mySecondClass").filter(":checked").closest("tr").remove();`

Comment: I cannot change them. anyway i can get their values using getparamvalues method..Thanks!

Comment: @user1016403 you cannot change them, really?! Why cannot you?

Comment: Question after question, you show very little effort. Seems like you want StackOverflow to write your code for you one problem at a time.

Comment: @Crazy, sorry..am new to jquery...

Comment: So learn it like everyone else. There's no shortage of tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is inefficient, this can be done in one call as follows:

`$('.mySecondClass:checked').closest('tr').remove();`

Comment: i think `.closest('tr')` is a better option than `.parents('tr:first')`